# n-layerd application and linqdatasource

Tags: binding, domain-driven-design, linqdatasource, n-layer

Asp.net application in a n-layered architecture (better if is a DDD architecture).

In the presentation layer I have a grid (let's say telerik radgrid or standard gridview) where I need to show a list of products (product is my entity).

Make sense talking about Linqdatasource provider for the grid? How can I use it in this scenario? Or I should write the binding operations "manully" (intercepiting the binding events and call my getproductlist function from my application layer?

Example are welcome...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The LinqDataSource/SqlDataSource/ObjectDataSource controls, in my experience, provide little in the way of development time and hinder maintainability. In general, my code for binding to a grid would look something like this:

```
using(ApplicationService appService = new ApplicationService())
{
    RadGrid1.DataSource = appService.GetCollection();
    RadGrid1.DataBind();
}
```

The application service would call the repository, where the Linq query would be performed. Some new techniques such as CQRS where your SQL query would only be 'SELECT * FROM TABLE' may be suited to the DataSource objects but I am left familliar with this.